# LLDB Restart process without user input

Tags: debugging, lldb

I am trying to debug a concurrent program in LLDB and am getting a seg fault, but not on every execution.  I would like to run my process over and over until it hits a seg fault.  So far, I have the following:

```
b exit
breakpoint com add 1
Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.
> run 
> DONE
```

The part that I find annoying, is that when I get to the exit function and hit my breakpoint, when the `run` command gets executed, I get the following prompt from LLDB:

```
There is a running process, kill it and restart?: [Y/n]
```

I would like to automatically restart the process, without having to manually enter `Y` each time.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could kill the previous instance by hand with `kill` - which doesn't prompt - then the `run` command won't prompt either.

Or:

```
(lldb) settings set auto-confirm 1
```

will give the default (capitalized) answer to all lldb queries.

Or if you have Xcode 6.x (or current TOT svn lldb) you could use the lldb driver's batch mode:

```
$ lldb --help
...
       -b 
       --batch 
            Tells the debugger to running the commands from -s, -S, -o & -O,
            and then quit.  However if any run command stopped due to a signal
            or crash, the debugger will return to the interactive prompt at the
            place of the crash.
```

So for instance, you could script this in the shell, running:

lldb  -b -o run

in a loop, and this will stop if the run ends in a crash rather than a normal exit.  In some circumstances this might be easier to do.

Comment: Perfect, each of these solutions are exactly what I wanted.  Thanks